# Hadoop upload files from local to HDFS

Tags: linux, hadoop, centos, hadoop2, centos7

i have a sample file called testfile.txt at `/home/hadoop/Desktop/testfile.txt`
i need to place it in hadoop fs `/mydata/testfolder`
when i fire the command the result is shown below:

```
# hadoop fs -put /home/hadoop/Desktop/testfile.txt /mydata/testfolder
  put: file /mydata/testfolder/testfile.txt._COPYING_ on client 192.168.52.132
```

when i check my testfolder there isn't any of my testfile.txt. Any idea?

Comment: try `hadoop fs -put /home/hadoop/Desktop/testfile.txt hdfs://namenode_host:port/mydata/testfolder`

Comment: @MRSrinivas, may i know which port should i use? i tried several ports from 50010,50020,50070. I am new into hadoop, sorry & thank u sir

Comment: the default port is 9000. check the config file core-site.xml, the value for fs.defaultFS

Comment: other way is you can get it in HDFS web UI typically which runs on `50070`.

Comment: @NirmalRam i've checked the core-site.xml. the default is 9000. Tried entering 9000, connection refused, 8020 has the same output as above.
is there other issues? thank you sirs

Comment: @MR Srinivas the HDFS web UI is able to run but cant find the testfile.txt in my Web UI

Comment: In web UI you can get `hdfs hostanme` and `port`

Comment: You can try this command 
_hadoop fs -copyFromLocal localpath hdfspath_

Comment: Try using `hdfs dfs -df -h`. You should see how much space is free if hdfs is working. It seems to me something is broken on your hdfs deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to check if -put was successful:

*echo $?*

Return value should be 0 if file copy was a success.

Additionally you can try these commands which works for me:

*hadoop dfs -mkdir -p mydata/testfolder*

*hadoop dfs -put /home/hadoop/Desktop/testfile.txt mydata/testfolder*

*hadoop dfs -ls mydata/testfolder*

Comment: does my hadoop has to be in the superuser access or in the normal user?

Comment: To run above commands you don't have to be in superuser mode. You should have a valid credentials for accessing hdfc.

Comment: Can you vote up the answer so that people having a similar problem can quickly check it? Thanks.

Comment: And to add to my above comment, you can accept this answer so that we can close this question as solved. - Thanks.

Comment: it says vote has been casted but i am less than 15 reputation, hence unable to display it publicly sorry @vmorusu